# Git push issue to local git repository?

Tags: git

I get the below error while pushing while if I try from someone else's computer the push are going through.. What could be the problem? On git repository on server I have given write access and security permissions to the group of which all users are part of.

```
$ git push origin master    
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 275 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object directory /<IP>/<Folder Name>/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: object directory /<IP>/<Folder Name>/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: refs/heads/dev does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
remote: fatal: bad object HEAD
error: object directory /<IP>/<Folder Name>/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: refs/heads/dev does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
fatal: bad object HEAD
To //<IP>/<Folder Name>/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to '//<IP>/<Folder Name>/'
```

Comment: Maybe this is relevant to you: https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/object-directory-does-not-exist-git-operations-fail-after-upgrade-or-stash_home-update-650413082.html

Comment: Have you tried pulling changes before pushing them?

Comment: Also try to see what git remote -v shows to you. Next, make a git fetch --all, and then try to synchronize with your repo, it might that somebody pushed something. Secondly, check if  your origin/master points to something, it looks like it does not point to anything. Finally, check if you have the permissions to push on master, although the error message is different when you do not have the permissions.

Comment: Nothing worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit strange, but I had an 2.11v installation on my machine and I reverted it to 2.9v which was basically the version of git on server and I was able to push without any problem to master branch as well as on development branch.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal `git push` operation, there are *two* computers, working two repositories, using some kind of over-the-internet "phone call" connection between them.  Your Git running on your computer hands objects (with their big ugly SHA-1 hash IDs) to their Git on their computer, and their computer stores those into their repository using whatever methods are appropriate for their computer, which may or may not be appropriate for yours.

When you do a purely local, on-one-computer "push", *your* computer takes on *both* roles.  Your Git has to play both sender, sending objects from your repository on your computer, and receiver, receiving objects into their repository on their computer.

***If***—this is a pretty big "if", and is clearly where things are going wrong here—both repositories really *are* on your computer, this all works, because your second Git, acting as receiver, running locally on your computer, stores object in "their" repository (which is really your own other repository) in a format suitable for your computer.  But if "their" repository is on a networked drive, or—as is obviously happening in this case—is using a networked drive that is accessible from *their* computer but not from *your* computer, when your computer tries to "play them" and access those networked-drive files from *your* system, it just doesn't work.

There are two solutions:

- Set up your computer so that you have the same access that they do, so that your Git's operation on the shared files works the same as their Git's operation on the shared files, so that when your Git "pretends to be them" it all just works.

  The details for doing this are, of course, dependent on networked-drive setups.  They will vary depending on OSes and server machines and so on.
- Stop trying to push locally: use their computer, which really does have access to their networked drives.  Give your objects to *their* Git on their computer.

Comment: The repository is on a remote server. There are two local users/systems. So from one system I tried to clone, edit, add, commit and push.. everything works but from other system it does not and I get the same error. Access and permission both the users are not same level.

Comment: The above all still applies: one computer—the one where this works—has access, and the other does not. When you tell Git to use a local operation, it believes it can do everything on its own, without firing up a second Git on a second computer. Either adjust things so that both computers have access, or stop using local protocols. (Though I see from your other comment that perhaps you have a bug in your Git 2.11 version—probably, that it thinks more/too-many things are local, vs the 2.9 version.)

Comment: Thanks torek, we will move our repo to github after few days, so may be then these errors would not occur.